# sbt mappings in Universal error after sbt upgrade to 0.13.13

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

```scala
mappings in Universal <++= (packageBin in Compile, sourceDirectory) map { (_, src) =>
  val confFiles = (src / "main" / "resources") ** "*.conf"
  confFiles.get.map(file => file -> ("conf/" + file.name))
},
```

Works but generates a compiler warning <++= has been deprecated. Changing the operator to ++= generates a compiler error

> error: No implicit for Append.Values[Seq[(java.io.File, String)], sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[Seq[(java.io.File, String)]]]] found,
>     so sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[Seq[(java.io.File, String)]]] cannot be appended to Seq[(java.io.File, String)]
>       mappings in Universal **++=** (packageBin in Compile, sourceDirectory) map { (_, src) =>

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it

> ```
> mappings in Universal ++= { (packageBin in Compile, sourceDirectory) map { (_, src) =>
> val confFiles = (src / "main" / "resources") ** "*.conf"
> confFiles.get.map(file => file -> ("conf/" + file.name))
> } 
> }.value,
> ```

Even better is

```
mappings in Universal ++= {
val src = sourceDirectory.value
val confFiles = (src / "main" / "resources") ** "*.conf"
confFiles.get.map(file => file -> ("conf/" + file.name))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This operator is very confusing. Try a simpler `:=` which is functionally equivalent:

```scala
mappings.in(Universal) := {
  // Dependency on packageBin (part of your previous definition).
  packageBin.in(Compile).value
  // Create the new mappings.
  val confFiles = (sourceDirectory.value / "main" / "resources") ** "*.conf"
  val newMappings = confFiles.get.map(file => file -> ("conf/" + file.name))
  // Append them manually to the previous value.
  mappings.in(Universal).value ++ newMappings
}
```

Comment: That wont work. newMappings creates a task that throws errors. Below is how I solved it